Aiogram 3, кнопка для инвайта бота в беседу или чат
Есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую должно всплывать диалоговое окно, в котором можно выбрать беседу и добавить бота, как реализовать?
main_kb_builder.button(text = "➕Добавить в канал", callback_data = "main_kb_callback_add")

Добавьте в кнопку ссылку формата https://t.me/my_bot?startgroup=start,
где my_bot - username вашего бота.
Это будет выглядеть так: main_kb_builder.button(text = "➕Добавить в канал", callback_data = "main_kb_callback_add", url="https://t.me/my_bot?startgroup=start")
